How do you finalize a PSBT when the last signature is provided by a HWW?
Most device APIs for HWI have a method sign_tx(tx: PSBT) that has a return type of PSBT. If the hardware device I'm interacting with provides the final signature necessary, how do I, from the output of the method, get a ready-to-broadcast PSBT?

Finalizing a PSBT does not require private keys so can be done by any external finalizer that understands the output script.
One such is Bitcoin Core and it's finalizepsbt RPC. This will create the final scriptSig and scriptWitness for each input that it understands that has signatures. If all inputs are finalized, it will also produce the raw transaction hex that can be broadcast with sendrawtransaction.
